# Why isn't there "I don't like this question" closure reason?

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons

As the comments to [this answer](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6762/21949) show, it seems to be normal on this SE to vote for closure just because the question is strongly disliked. The reported reason will not necessarily apply: it will be chosen just because *some* reason has to be chosen.

So, why not to make things unambiguous by just adding an "I don't like this question" closure reason?

The absence of such a reason would only make sense if questions could be closed by moderators only — because they still can be held to some standards of objectivity and impartiality more or less. Ordinary users' decisions to vote for closure can't be held to standards. Thus, *not* having the subject reason in the list appears to be plain hypocrisy. So why not just call things what they are?

Comment: Just because someone doesn't like a question isn't a reason to close it and the comments on that question are not suggesting that it was closed just because they don't like it.. There are other close reasons that could have been chosen to close that question such as the one for a push question/attacking someone because your question is suggesting that poor people should be prevented from having children,

Comment: @JoeW But no one chose that reason. The 5 people chose the one that didn't apply because they didn't care what reason to choose just because they wanted to close the question just because they didn't like it.

Comment: That was the reason with the most votes but that doesn't mean that is what everyone chose.

Comment: I think this question describes an XY problem. You ask for something that you probably don't want to have (or you do, then one could formulated it more positively like: please add close reason X) but you really want to say that questions get unfairly closed. Now that would have been an interesting question. How do we know that close voters actually do their job well? But this isn't what the question asks.

Answer (score 3):

Q: *So, why not to make things unambiguous by just adding an "I don't like this question" closure reason?*

In part, because "I don't like this question" is ambiguous as to why one does not like the question. It provides no clue as to how the question may be improved to the point of the closer *liking* the question and retracting their close vote.

The existing close reasons, at least, suggest how the question may be improved.

Comment: Well, it turns out that when you just don't like the very topic raised or the angle it is approached at, there is nothing to improve.

Comment: @Greendrake - In that case, a downvote for "not useful" would seem appropriate.

Comment: This answer is missing the point that existing closure reasons are often chosen by regular users _arbitrarily_, just to close questions they don't like. There is no mechanism to ensure that the chosen reason really is the one they want to close the question for. "I just don't like it", although not helpful, would have been at least sincere and accurate.

Comment: @Greendrake Lets be honest here, your question and comments seem to be focused on who should and shouldn't be allowed to "breed" which should have been the target of the close reason because of this. "The primary purpose of this question appears to be to promote or discredit a specific political cause, group or politician. It does not appear to be a good-faith effort to learn more about governments, policies and political processes as defined in the help center."

Comment: @JoeW That's false. The question asks what it does at face value. The notion of birth control was given only as one of the two examples of how the issue could possibly be managed. Whilst I may indeed have an opinion "on who should and shouldn't be allowed to "breed"" readable between the lines, the question is most definitely _not focused_ on it. Comments may be, but they were answering questions in the above comments.

Comment: @Greendrake Here is one of the comments in question. "Well, at least in this case, the poverty would not have been "inter-generational" if they did not breed." That is clearly stating that you think that they should not be breeding.

Comment: @JoeW So what? What do my own thoughts have to do with the question in which they do not appear?

Comment: @Greendrake They go to show your motivation behind asking the question which goes to the close reason that I mentioned before.

Comment: @JoeW You can't accuse people of wishing to push something just because they support it and ask a tangentially related question.

Comment: @Greendrake I am stating that is what your comments suggest and what the reason the question should be closed as.

Comment: @Greendrake Please note that you should not be openly supporting *anything* in this community. [This is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Philipp I don't support anything _openly_. My support was inferred in the comment above, and I simply don't deny it in the response.